# Calcular quantidade total e valor total SQL Server com três tabelas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Sds, estou com um problema, não estou conseguindo agrupar os municípios no meu SELECT. Mesmo com o group by os municipios ficam separados. São três tabelas diferentes, municipio, produto e unidade. preciso calcular quantidade total e valor total de 'Omeprazol 10mg' por municipio.

```
SELECT ( dbo.tb_municipio.des_municipio ), 
       Sum(dbo.tb_produto.qtd_produto)                             AS TOTAL_SOMA 
       , 
       ( dbo.tb_produto.val_produto * dbo.tb_produto.qtd_produto ) AS 
       TOTAL_VALOR 
FROM   dbo.tb_municipio 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tb_unidade 
               ON dbo.tb_municipio.cod_municipio = dbo.tb_unidade.cod_municipio 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tb_produto 
               ON dbo.tb_unidade.cod_unidade = dbo.tb_produto.cod_unidade 
WHERE  des_produto = 'Omeprazol 10mg' 
GROUP  BY dbo.tb_municipio.des_municipio, 
          dbo.tb_produto.qtd_produto, 
          dbo.tb_produto.val_produto
```

este é o resultado que está dando, o meu objetivo é que fique tudo agrupado, todos os produtos de salvador em uma unica linha.

```
des_muni  Total Soma  Total Valor
Salvador   80         25.60
Salvador   100        32.00
Salvador   5000       1600.00
SãoPaulo   30         15.00
```

Se faltou alguma informação, posto logo em sequencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agrupar tudo, você precisa fazer duas coisas nessa query:

Utilizar o `SUM` também no cálculo de `TOTAL_VALOR`:

```
SUM( dbo.tb_produto.val_produto * dbo.tb_produto.qtd_produto ) AS TOTAL_VALOR
```

E deixar no group by, apenas o `dbo.tb_municipio.des_municipio`:

```
GROUP  BY dbo.tb_municipio.des_municipio
```

---

Sua query então ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT dbo.tb_municipio.des_municipio , 
       Sum(dbo.tb_produto.qtd_produto) AS TOTAL_SOMA ,
       Sum( dbo.tb_produto.val_produto * dbo.tb_produto.qtd_produto ) AS TOTAL_VALOR 
 FROM  dbo.tb_municipio 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tb_unidade 
               ON dbo.tb_municipio.cod_municipio = dbo.tb_unidade.cod_municipio 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tb_produto 
               ON dbo.tb_unidade.cod_unidade = dbo.tb_produto.cod_unidade 
 WHERE des_produto = 'Omeprazol 10mg' 
 GROUP BY dbo.tb_municipio.des_municipio
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! você e o colega acima me salvaram, esse pequeno detalhe estava me matando rs

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque o `GROUP BY` agrupa os campos iguais, e no seu caso os totais não são. Quando usamos funções de agragação ( `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc), essas não precisam estar no  `GROUP BY`, só os demais campos do `SELECT`.

O `dbo.tb_produto.qtd_produto` já está sendo computado com a função  `SUM`, então não precisa estar no `GROUP BY`.  Agora para agrupar tudo, precisa usar uma função com que chamou de "TOTAL_VALOR", senão não vai agrupar. Tente usar `SUM(dbo.tb_produto.val_produto * dbo.tb_produto.qtd_produto)` e remover esse campo também do `GROUP BY`, deixando somente `dbo.tb_municipio.des_municipio`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!